# Class alternative for jquery selectors

Tags: jquery

I have some code like below

```
<li class="active-always"><a href="#tab-03" data-toggle="tab">Alabama</a></li>
<li class="active-always"><a href="#tab-04" data-toggle="tab">Alaska</a></li>
<li class="active-always"><a href="#tab-05" data-toggle="tab">Arizona</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-06" data-toggle="tab">California</a></li> 
<li><a href="#tab-07" data-toggle="tab">Colorado</a></li>
```

Here I am selecting `<li>` elements which doesnt have class `active-always`

```
$('li:not(.active-always)').addClass('disabled')
```

But I am not sure if I am doing it correct. There must be a better solution. Because sometimes using class names becomes confusing. Often I forget the purpose of this kind of class names.

> And I ask myself, was it for CSS or JS?

Is there any simple alternative for this?

I know if I add some own producton tag attributes like

```
<li flag-active-always><a href="#tab-05" data-toggle="tab">Arizona</a>
```

My code becomes invalid. Is there any valid solution for this? Maybe `data-active-always` can be a solution.

Is there any other valid attribute prefix like `data-...`?

Is it valid to use this kind of tag attributes without values.`data-active-always` instead of `data-active-always="true"`?

Comment: Using a  `data-*` attribute without value doesn't make sense. Then you will probably ask yourself: Was this `data-*` attribute for storing data or a selector? :)

Comment: @Vohuman: There is nothing wrong with boolean attributes though.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, that's true.

Comment: @Vohuman Thats why I am asking for data-* alternative. :)

Comment: Are you looking for `$('li:not([data-active-always])').addClass('disabled')`?

Comment: @green Nope. I am looking for `$('li:not([my-unique-and-valid-attribute-which-can-not-be-used-for-storing-data])').addClass('disabled')`

Comment: @Jaxovee Tried `$('li:not([data-active-always​])').addClass('disabled')` ? `data-*` should not have to have a value set.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly your use case is. I don't see anything wrong with using classes personally.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it valid to use this kind of tag attributes without
>   values.data-active-always instead of data-active-always="true"?

`data-*` attribute should not need to have value set , though may not be valid `XHTML`

```js
$("li:not([data-active-always])").addClass("disabled");
```

```css
.disabled a {
  color:gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="active-always"><a href="#tab-03" data-toggle="tab">Alabama</a></li>
<li data-active-always><a href="#tab-04" data-toggle="tab">Alaska</a></li>
<li data-active-always><a href="#tab-05" data-toggle="tab">Arizona</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-06" data-toggle="tab">California</a></li> 
<li><a href="#tab-07" data-toggle="tab">Colorado</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Data attributes are not part of any XHTML doctype anyway. The only possible appearance of data attributes in XHTML is XHTML5, which is nothing more than an XML serialization of HTML5. The problem is that the HTML5 spec doesn't specify if data attributes must have values, but it seems to imply and assume that they do, at least when mapped to the dataset.

Comment: @BoltClock  `html` at http://jsfiddle.net/gt6nmpu9/ did not appear to return errors at https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: Interesting. Maybe they just allow it because they don't outright forbid it.

Comment: @BoltClock Not certain. Would probably add a `=""` , here ; though appear not required. Why initially posted about `XHTML` ; attempting to indicate `XML` parsing of document would probably throw error at `data-*` without at least a closing `=""`

Comment: Ah yeah, I missed that. Generally if you want to specify that as a Boolean attribute in XHTML you would have to write `data-active-always="data-active-always"` (XML doesn't *have* a concept of Boolean attributes, but that is how XHTML maps Booleans from HTML).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using data-flag-always is valid. But you are on the right track, try the removal selector .not() which will search for classes specifically:

```js
$('li').not('.active-always').addClass('disabled');
```

```css
.disabled > a {
    color: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="active-always"><a href="#tab-03" data-toggle="tab">Alabama</a></li>
<li class="active-always"><a href="#tab-04" data-toggle="tab">Alaska</a></li>
<li class="active-always"><a href="#tab-05" data-toggle="tab">Arizona</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-06" data-toggle="tab">California</a></li> 
<li><a href="#tab-07" data-toggle="tab">Colorado</a></li>
```